# Calendar-Group visible for someone outsite of the group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, groups

I have the following problem:

I created a calendar on my site. The site has about 5 different groups which are separated. For example:

Group 1: Person A, B, C
Group 2: Person D, E, F
Group 3: Person G, H, I
...

Person A can only see the calendar entries of B and C. Now my question: Is is possible that I can allow person A to see the entries of Group 3 without having to add person A to group 3?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am no quite sure about how you set up the permissions, but for existing entries, you can simply share the events directly to Person A so he can view them.

Comment: That is possible, but I have about 20 people per group, and I want person A to see everything within group C. There will always be someone that forgets to share it to person A. It would be OK if everyone could see all groups, without being in every group. Is that possible? Because person A sees only group 1.

Comment: @Tom, Sorry I get bit confused. You are saying it is acceptable that everyone could see all groups, without being in every group. I will assume you want all the entries will be visible to all users. One ultimate way will be creating a unique permission in that calendar, then grant all the users permission level high enough like full control.